# How to copy project target folder to destination location using maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I am migrating my application from JBoss 6 AS to Wildfly 8 AS. As a part of hard deploy, `jboss-maven-plugin` was employed.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy_ear</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hard-deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <deploySubDir>./</deploySubDir>
                        <fileName>target/${project.build.finalName.full}</fileName>
                        <unpack>true</unpack>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In wilfdly 8, I am trying to unpack ear file in `standalone/deployments` folder and as a part of it, I tried `maven-dependency-plugin` for copying ear file  but it is not working.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        ???
                        <outputDirectory>${jboss.home}/${jboss.configuration.name}/deployments/test.ear</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have the code related to building ear and unpacking the built ear file in the same pom.xml. Can anyone please help me with the configuration as the below tags are pointing to repository configured and hence, resulting in build failure.

```
<artifactItems>
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>                                  
</artifactItem>
```

How can I point to project build target directory and copy unpacked ear file content in the destination folder.

Comment: How about using [wildfly maven plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/usage.html)

Comment: Application needs changing some configuration files after unpacking the ear and hence, going with the unpacking model with auto-deploy-exploded property set to true.

Comment: Your configuration should be externalised. Embedding configuration in your application is an anti-pattern in many circles.

Comment: You are right .. Steve. I will be moving out the unpacking part. Many thanks.